# Drupal 7 - Theme the user profile form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to theme my Drupal site's user profile form at the moment. I'm using hook_form_alter in the theme's template.php file.

The code is the same as the code I've used to edit another form but for some reason I can't spot it's not working.

```
function THEME_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {      
        $form['current_pass']['#prefix'] = '<div class="loginFormBlock">';
        $form['current_pass']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
        $form['current_pass']['#size'] = '500';
        //$form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'image_button', '#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/Login.png');
    } 
}
```

Now the commented out submit button part works when it's un commented but the current_pass bits don't do anything. Current_pass is the name of the field I'm trying to theme. THEME_NAME has been replaced by the theme's name.

**ANSWER:**

As suggested I looked into the $form array.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($form);
echo '</pre>';
```

Saw that current_pass was in the account array and amended the code to the following, which works fine.

```
$form['account']['current_pass']['#size'] = '500';
```

Hopefully this can help someone else.

Comment: current_pass is an existing profile field ? try to debug and make a dump of `$form['current_pass']` (before altering it) to see what is inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going to say same thing - do a dump of $form and make sure that the field actually exists - if it does and it still doesn't work then there may be another hook being called after yours and changing your changes.

ps: I am still using D6 but are you sure your putting your form_alter function in the right place? yours says THEME_NAME_form_alter - I know in D6 you have to put them in module layer not the theme layer (unless this has changed in D7???) - could this be your issue?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the answer into the question for future users.

Comment: glad to have helped! so I take it in D7 this has now changed :D can't wait to do a project in it! any more questions gives a shout!